# MySQL Trigger to change date value to weekstart before insert or update

Tags: mysql, database, date, triggers

I have a table with a date column that should always be the the first day of the week for each entry.

Is there a way I can create a trigger that will change the input value to the corresponding start date?

For instance, if i have:

```
insert into `Customer`.`Orders`
(`week`,`name`,`mon`,`tue`,`wed`,`thu`,`fri`)
values
('2018-02-27','John','12','14','0','3','44');
```

Can i somehow have the trigger get that date value and replace it with the weekstart? I was able to the get weekstart for a specific date with the following:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2018-02-27', INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK('2018-02-27')-1 DAY);
```

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look into a BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers; and put something like this in the their bodies.

```
SET NEW.`week` = DATE_SUB(NEW.`week`, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NEW.`week`)-1 DAY)
```

This is assuming your calculation is correct.